# with-nx.js: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: next.js, azure-pipelines, nrwl-nx

I'm building my Next/NX application using an Azure build pipeline. The build is a success, but when starting the application, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\xxx\dist\apps\launchpad-app\next.config.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
```

The problem is, that in the **`with-nx.js`**, the **`workspaceRoot`** is set incorrectly, as the path is not correctly escaped:

```js
function getWithNxContext() {
return {
workspaceRoot: 'D:\a\1\s',
libsDir: 'libs'
}
```

`D:\a\1\s` should have been `D:\\a\\1\\s`.

How do I ensure that the `workspaceRoot` is escaped correctly?

The `.yml` build file is:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- powershell: |
    npm install
    npm ci
    npm run buildprod
  displayName: 'Build application'
```

Buildprod is this command:

```
"buildprod": "nx run app:build:production --skip-nx-cache",
```

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and could not work out how to fix it. The fix I came up with is part of my deployment process, which searches for the string value and replaces it with a string value which has the correct escape sequence.

So in my YAML file, which is run in devops, I build and export all my apps which are saved in my `ArtifactStagingDirectory`; I then call a PowerShhell script which will install the node modules for each app and zip them up so I can deploy to the correct Azure Web App.

```yaml
 - script: node ./.azure-pipelines/run-many.js "$(COMMANDS)" build
   displayName: "build apps"

 - script: node ./.azure-pipelines/run-many.js "$(COMMANDS)" export
   displayName: "export apps"

 - powershell: ./.azure-pipelines/app-install-zip.ps1 "$(COMMANDS)" '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\dist\apps\' '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\apps'
   displayName: 'Install & Zip Apps'
```

I was already using a PowerShell script as part of my deployment pipeline, so I just updated that script to edit the file which is causing the issue.

The three params being passed to my PowerShell script would look like:

```
Value : ['core','homepage']
Path : 'D:\a\1\s\dist\apps\'
ExportPath : 'D:\a\1\a\apps'
```

**`app-install-zip.ps1`**

```ps
    param (
        $value,
        $path,
        $exportPath
    )
    $valueArray = $value.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Replace("'","").Replace(" ", "").Split(',')

    Write-Output "The array of Apps is : $valueArray"
    Write-Output "The path is : $path"
    Write-Output "The export path is : $exportPath"

    $valueArray | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Output "Running for App : $_"
        $combinedValue = $path + $_
        Write-Output "The app path is : $combinedValue"

        Write-Output "Changing the directory to $combinedValue"
        Set-Location $combinedValue
    
        Write-Output "Running npm install"
        npm install

        Write-Output "Zipping exported folder if it exists"
        if ((Test-Path $($combinedValue + "\exported") -PathType Container)) {
            Write-Output "The exported path exists at : $($combinedValue + "\exported")"

            write-Output "Creating the staging directory if it does not exist"
            if (!(Test-Path $exportPath -PathType Container)) {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $exportPath
            }

            Write-Output "Zipping exported folder"
            Compress-Archive -Path $($combinedValue + "\exported\*") -DestinationPath "$($exportPath + "\export-" + $_).zip" -Force
        }

        Write-Output "Testing to see if the with-nx.js file exists"
        $file = "D:\a\1\s\dist\apps\" + $_ + "\.nx-helpers\with-nx.js"
        if (Test-Path $file -PathType Leaf) {
            Write-Output "The file exists at : $file"
            $originalValue = "workspaceRoot: 'D:\a\1\s',"
            $newValue = "workspaceRoot: 'D:\\a\\1\\s',"

            $content = Get-Content -Path $file -Raw
            $newContent = $content -replace [regex]::Escape($originalValue), $newValue
            Set-Content -Path $file -Value $newContent
            Write-Output "The file has been updated"
        }

        Write-Output "Zipping App project for deployment"
        Compress-Archive -Path $($combinedValue + "\*") -DestinationPath "$($exportPath + "\app-" + $_).zip" -Force

    }
```

This is how I fixed the issue, but this seems like a bit of a hack and I am sure there would be an easier way to update the `workspaceRoot` value, but I was unable to find another solution. The fix always assumes that the `workspaceRoot` is a fixed value, which I know so I can replace it with the correct value for that I need.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more details. I still feel this is not the correct fix for the issue, but after 2 days of searching I used this to get around the issue. I will update the answer if I ever find the solution which I feel is the correct answer which fixes the main underlying issue with the "workspaceRoot" value.